# Inserting a new line using DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I'm attempting to insert a new node into an XML document.  I'm using simpleXML for most of the parsing but for this piece I need to use DOM.  This is the function i'm using to make the addition

```
function simplexml_insert_after(SimpleXMLElement $sxe, SimpleXMLElement $insert, SimpleXMLElement $target)   
 {
    $target_dom = dom_import_simplexml($target);
    $target_dom->formatOutput = true;
    $target_dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $insert_dom = $target_dom->ownerDocument->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($insert), true);
    if ($target_dom->nextSibling) {
        return $target_dom->parentNode->insertBefore($insert_dom, $target_dom->nextSibling);
    } else {
        return $target_dom->parentNode->appendChild($insert_dom);
    }
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
$meta2 = new SimpleXMLElement("<meta/>");
$meta2->addAttribute('name', 'subject');
$meta2->addAttribute('value', $doc_id); 
$target = current($my_xml->xpath('//meta[last()]'));
simplexml_insert_after($my_xml, $meta2, $target);
```

My Problem is that its inserting the new node immediately after the target rather than on a new line so the resulting XML looks like this:

```
<meta content="a" name="ap-category"/>
<meta content="bx" name="ap-format"/><meta name="subject" value="urn:blah"/>
```

When I'd like it to look like this:

```
<meta content="a" name="ap-category"/>
<meta content="bx" name="ap-format"/>
<meta name="subject" value="urn:blah"/>
```

I've tried changing preserveWhiteSpace to true, but it did not help.  How do i go about adding a new line before inserting that node?

**edit**
Here is the fix that worked:

```
 function simplexml_insert_after(SimpleXMLElement $sxe, SimpleXMLElement $insert,SimpleXMLElement $target)   
 {
     $target_dom = dom_import_simplexml($target);
     $target_dom->formatOutput = true;
     $target_dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
     $insert_dom = $target_dom->ownerDocument->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($insert), true);
     if ($target_dom->nextSibling) {
          $result = $target_dom->parentNode->insertBefore($insert_dom, $target_dom->nextSibling);
          $target_dom->parentNode->insertBefore($target_dom->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n"), $result);
          return $result
     } else {
          return $target_dom->parentNode->appendChild($insert_dom);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to insert a textnode just before the element you want to insert, something like this:

```
function simplexml_insert_after(SimpleXMLElement $sxe, 
                                SimpleXMLElement $insert, 
                                SimpleXMLElement $target)   
{
    $target_dom = dom_import_simplexml($target);
    $target_dom->formatOutput = true;
    $target_dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $document = $target_dom->ownerDocument;
    $insert_dom = $document->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($insert), true);

    $parentNode = $target_dom->parentNode;
    if ($target_dom->nextSibling) {
        $result = $parentNode->insertBefore($insert_dom, $target_dom->nextSibling);
        $parentNode->insertBefore($document->createTextNode("\n"), $result);
        return $result
    } else {
        return $parentNode->appendChild($insert_dom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I think this is on the right track, but at the moment when make that change i get this message:
`Call to undefined method DOMElement::createTextNode()`

Comment: try $target_dom->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n"), as createTextNode is a DomDocument Method (I don't have php on hand just now and can't try by myself)

Comment: You rock, that fixed it.  I am still new to DOM, but I should have caught that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method call to this:

```
simplexml_insert_after($my_xml, "\n" . $meta2, $target);
```

...with `preserveWhiteSpace = true;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately, it gives me this error:
     Argument 2 passed to simplexml_insert_after() must be an object   of class SimpleXMLElement